# HTML Form: if X value equals a number, display information (Excel spreadsheet)

Tags: html, database, excel, spreadsheet

I have an Excel spreadsheet with some information about an event we're going to host. Imagine something like this:
Name | Code Number | Date of Birth | Etc.

There's about 40 people in there. And I want to create a simple html file in which, when someone enters their code number (say, 12345678A), the rest of their info (Name, DOB, Etc.) will be displayed. It's nothing confidential so we don't need PHP, only easy HTML.

Is this possible? Does anyone of you know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the connection between PHP and confidential?

Comment: @teylyn no idea, I'm not really aware of much PHP stuff. I can work a little with HTML but that's about it. What I meant is that I didn't really need a database or anything, I just wanted to know if, by using HTML there was a way to display X info if Y is input and W info if Z is input.

Comment: You could use a javascript form, but a dynamic link to an Excel file is pretty much impossible. With only 40 records you could even have the data sitting in the Javascript somewhere.

Comment: @teylyn Well that sounds good! Thanks! Is there any way to easily do it? Like a website that does it for you or some template code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your Excel file to [OneDrive](http://onedrive.live.com). It's free online storage by Microsoft. All you need is a Microsoft ID, which takes about 10 seconds to set up.

Store the file in the Public folder, then right-click and select "Embed". That will give you the code you need to embed your spreadsheet into a web site.

For an example see [my blog post here](http://www.teylyn.com/percentage-charts-with-conditional-formatting/). You can edit the blue cell and hit enter, then formulas will re-calculate the spreadsheet.

So create a workbook with a user interface you want to present on the web and let Excel do the magic in the background.